# Cannot connect CakePHP with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

I am getting an error when i load my index.php of cakePHP through localhost, which says

> Fatal Error
>
> Error: Class 'Mongo' not found     File:
>   /var/www/html/cake/lib/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php
>   Line: 105

What might be the mistake i am committing over here.

I have all the files in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the MongoDB module for php and make sure it's activated.

[Instructions are here.](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php)